# Is there a way to audit who is changing the system time?

Tags: openvpn, date, ntp

I've got an openvpn client running which seems to be causing a problem on my system by changing the system time for my machine.

[How do you prevent openvpn clients from changing the system clock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1473593)

Is there a way that I can isolate changes to the system time in Linux system logs (Ubuntu) to understand who is changing the system time, when they are changing it, and why?

example:

```
cat ./syslog | egrep -i '(date|time)'
```

Comment: (migrated from SO) do you suspect an unknown user or a program you control?

Comment: do you share the system with another operating system?

Comment: It's not a shared system. Exclusivly Ubuntu. The issue is either NTP or timedatectl has a bug in it and it's updating the time to the wrong time or openvpn is executing a script which is also setting the time, even though I haven't found it yet in spite of my looking through all of the scripts openvpn executes. I need to know and understand which service to blame and then look at. Is it OpenVpn and I just missed it, or is it systemd-timedatectl?

Comment: How about making a `date` script and place it before `/usr/bin/` in PATH and add logging to that script and let that call `/usr/bin/date`?  (log the pid and related processes).

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a full answer, but also too much for a comment - I hope it might still help you.

If you want to go all-in you need to check which clock actually changes as there are multiple and most of them are [stacked delta on top of the other](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-date-time-from-linux-command-prompt/).

For example if you are now after the one that is controlled by [clock_settime](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/tree/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_settime.c) as used by e.g. the `date` command to set time you could consider tracing any invocation of that system call via [ftrace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/trace/ftrace.html).

But that might be a bit too much, most commonly "time changes on network change" is due to DHCP being allowed to push ntp server information to a system. If it now happens that your openvpn connection might run dhlient (uncommon but possible) or has set explicit option to [push info through dhcp](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/pushing-dhcp-options-to-clients/) it might happen that you get a nameserver set that does cause your system to change time.

In general checking ntp configuration like `timedatectl timesync-status` and/or `chronyc sources` (if you have it installed over systemd-timesyncd) changes pre/post openvpn dial-in would be a great start.
If it does the place I'd debug first, if it uses something like `dhclient` directly you can - for example - disable the ntp options in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` which will make the client not asking for those anymore.

The whole problem has too many "what if" and "it depends" to create a perfect answer. But maybe this gives you enough to add more detail to the question in the first place :-).